# Python bs4 find_all() not showing me text I looked up in HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I used Python BeautifulSoup4 and Requests to get data from this website: http://www.weather.gov/ctp/. I wanted my program to return the text from the [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ORfo.png) but I got nothing in my output.

Here is my code:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
doc = r.get("http://www.weather.gov/ctp/")
soup = bs(doc.content, "html.parser")
# I tried all of these methods to get "Weather.gov" as a returned string but none of them worked!
link1 = soup.find_all('href="http://www.weather.gov"')
link2 = soup.find_all("a", {'href':'http://www.weather.gov'})
link3 = soup.select('href["http://www.weather.gov"]')
for item in link3:
    print item.contents
# This loop does not return anything in the console
```

I tried using the same method to retrieve text from another part of the site and it worked. I am experiencing the same exact problem for another website but this time with a number. I try to retrieve that number as a value that can be assigned to a variable and I get nothing despite the fact that after testing the output for a value I get True but in the console there is nothing.

Comment: `link2` works. The other links are just incorrect selectors.

Answer (score 0):

> soup.select('a[href="http://www.weather.gov"]')

`tag[attribute='attribute_value']`

Read more at [BS Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment